# JOI or express-validator vs Mongodb validation

Tags: mongodb, schema, joi, node-mongodb-native, express-validator

I am new to MongoDB-native driver and want to create a strict schema. I am confused about whether to use MongoDB validation on the database level or use server validators like JOI or express-validator.
Which will be better and why?
Should I go for MongoDB validation, JOI or express-validator?

Explanation of the use case.

I have collection 'users' like this.
_id

name

username   (required)

email      (required)

password   (required)

A collection forms like this.

_id

user_id    (refers to users table _id key)

name

fields     (object)

I am creating an API so data in the wrong format will break things, that's why I need some kind of validation.